# Выровнять <div> по вертикали

Tags: html, css

Есть  блок с длинным текстом и такими параметрами:

```css
.preview {
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 380px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">Длинный текст</div>
```

И как только я его не пытался выровнять по вертикали, ничего не работает, не `vertical-align`, ни `margin` и тд. Как его можно выровнять по вертикали? Если указывать отступы сверху и снизу пикселями, то все работает, а автоматически - нет.

**UPD:** Возможно я плохо описал проблему, извиняюсь. Блок должен центрироваться по вертикали внутри основного блока с учетом всего содержимого внутри. Допустим если останется свободными `200px` из `400`, то он должен быть по центру этих `200` пикселей.

Comment: А у родительского элемента высота какая?

Comment: @Romchik, `400px`, в этом блоке есть еще картинка, но если `margin` в пикселях, то он берет картинку в расчет

Comment: А нужно именно на css? Можно в две строчки на js.

Comment: @Rennorb, можно и js. Мне просто не пришли мысли, как на JS это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно для этого использовать flexbox в комбинции с `margin`, который для детей flex-контейнера максимально смещает элементы (в данном случае нужен `margin-top: auto` и `margin-bottom: auto`). Тогда удастся избежать вложенных flex-элементов и абсолютного позиционирования. Демонтрация:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* располагать элементы по левую сторону, а не растягивать их по умолчанию */
  align-items: flex-start;

  /* Задаём высоту чисто для демонстрации, это необязательно */
  height: 400px;
}

.preview {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

/* Стили для демонстрации */
* { outline: 1px dotted gray; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="">
  <div class="preview">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eum harum, nam nulla numquam obcaecati optio pariatur velit voluptates voluptatum! Amet excepturi ipsam ipsum laudantium minus natus obcaecati porro voluptas.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Тогда такой вариант:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  flex-grow: 0;
  align-self: start;
}

.v-center {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.preview {
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 380px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/* Ненужное оформление */

.container {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.v-center {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}

.preview {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="">
  <div class="v-center">
    <div class="preview">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eum harum, nam nulla numquam obcaecati optio pariatur velit voluptates voluptatum! Amet excepturi ipsam ipsum laudantium minus natus obcaecati porro voluptas.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю оно центрируется без учета содержимого внутри родительского элемента. Добавил описание в UPD вопроса

Comment: Просто там стояла фиксированная высота. Если ее убрать, то высота будет динамичская и блок будет выравниваться динамически. Высота была изначально в вашем примере.

Comment: Высота фиксированная у основного блока и этого с текстом. У меня же проблема в том, чтобы этот блок выравнивался в оставшемся пространстве основоного блока. Допустим в эти `400 px` я занял `200 `картинкой и этот блок с текстом должен выравниваться в этих  `200` пикселях

Comment: Посмотрите, обновил. Оно?

Comment: Я немного не понял структуру, но если я правильно понял, то не совсем, текст не должен наползать на изображение.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант `блок`, который нужно отцентрировать **сделать дочерним**. И применить `line-height: высота, по которой нужно выровнять`.

```
.child {
    line-height: 1.25; /* по стандарту */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.preview {
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 380px;
  font-size: 13px;
  min-height: 90px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.parent {
  line-height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="preview">
    <h1>Много текста</h1>
    <p>Длинный текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно приспособить вариант `position:absolute; top:calc(50% - 90px);`

Comment: Абсолютное позиционирование не дружит с изменяемым содержимым внутри блока :( Добавил в UPD вопроса

Comment: А если попробовать дать всем дочернему(ним) элементам позиционирование: position:relative;

Comment: Это, к сожалению, не решает проблемы

Answer (score 0):

```css
.preview {
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 380px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border:1px solid red;
  line-height:90px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">Длинный текст</div>
```

Comment: Тут насколько я понимаю выравнивается текст, а мне нужно выравнивание самого блока.

Comment: Сорри, не понял сразу.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // 1. Если высота .preview не известна
 .preview {
      text-align: left;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      width: 380px;
     margin: 0 10px;
      font-size: 13px;
      background-color:green;

    }
.box{
     height:400px;
     background-color:red;
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;
}
// 2. Если высота .preview  известна
 .previewFix {
      text-align: left;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      width: 380px;
      height: 90px;
      margin: 0 10px;
      font-size: 13px;
      background-color:green;
      position:absolute;
      top:50%;
      margin-top:-45px; // половина своей высоты
    }
.boxFix{
     height:400px;
     width:400px;
     background-color:yellow;
     position:relative;
}
<div class="box">
    <div class="preview">Длинный текст Длинный текст Длинный текстДлинный текст</div>
</div>

<div class="boxFix">
    <div class="previewFix">Длинный текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Высота известна, но кроме текста в основном блоке есть еще картинка, и получается блок с текстом позиционируется по центру основного, без учета другого содержимого основного блока

Answer (score 0):

Тогда можно попробовать с flex и пустым третьим дивом:

```css
 .preview {
      text-align: left;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      width: 380px;
      margin: 0 10px;
      font-size: 13px;
      background-color:green;

    }
.box{
     height:400px;
     background-color:red;
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:column;
     justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, necessitatibus.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">Длинный текст Длинный текст Длинный текстДлинный текст</div>
    <div class="content0"></div>
</div>
```